# How to find the connected application from the endpoint

Tags: tooling-api

There is a spike in API calls being made with my user. I cannot figure out which application is causing these spikes. I created a ticket with Salesforce and the only information they can give me is that I need to find the application that is making the query to endpoint /services/data/v50.0/tooling/query.

Can anyone please help with this? I don't know how to find the application that is using that endpoint.

Comment: I don't really think you can. Most of what the connected app is for is to enable you to get an Access Token by going through an OAuth flow. Once you get the token, there is no distinction between "you" and "something using the token" (i.e. the Access Token says nothing about who/what the user is, it only says what can be done on Salesforce).

Comment: First thought that comes to mind: Go to your user details (click the profile icon -> settings -> advanced user details) and start revoking the items in the "OAuth Apps" related list one by one (taking time to measure API usage) until you see a noticeable drop in API usage.

Comment: if you have salesforce event monitoring, you can see the IP addresses of the requesting app which might be a clue; if you suspect a 3rd party app, it is always a good idea to use a dedicated service account user (this aids immeasurably in traceability) - though for you, the horse has left the barn

Comment: I tried your suggestion @DerekF and revoked all connected apps. My API calls are still spiking. Would you know what could be causing this if not a connected app?
The IP address making these calls is coming from my IP address.